# Setting the foreground color of the page

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi in my application i displaying the news details. It contains template(hedaline, said by and story). I need to set the foreground of the each textblock as "White" irrespective of the theme color change. Is there any common plalce set the foreground color so it will affect whole page.

Please help me , dont tell me to set the foreground to all textblocks.

Comment: You should define a `Style` and set the `Style` of each `Textblock`s

Comment: @ willmel I am doing this one .. whether Its not possible set to page.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a `Style` (without a `x:Key`) for a `TextBlock` and it'll automatically affect all `TextBlock` in your application.

Comment: Is this Mango only? Didn't think this worked in 7.0. Pretty cool if it does now :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it only affects the whole page, add a `Foreground` color to the page like this,

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" ...
```

Please note that if you apply any style to your `TextBlocks` on this page, this color (in this case `PhoneAccentBrush`) will be overwritten by the color defined in the `TextBlock`'s style.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this link http://innovativesingapore.com/2010/08/experession_phone/ for creating style as follows

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>            
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And apply to the Text blocks as

```
<TextBlock Height="49" Name="textblock" Margin="67,49,0,0" Text="WhiteForegroundText"  Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" />
```